# How to make control characters visible in string?

Tags: php, string

I was wondering if it is possible to make control characters in a string visible.

```
    $mystring = "Test\n";
    echo $mystring;
```

This will output `Test` but i don't want PHP to translate `\n` it should just output `Test\n` (For debugging purposes). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Put it between single quotes:

```
$mystring = 'Test\n';
echo $mystring; //Returns Test\n
```

Answer (score 2):

Use escape sequence with double quotes `"` or just enclose string in single quotes `'`.

```
$mystring = "Test\\n";
echo $mystring;

$mystring = 'Test\n';
echo $mystring;
```

https://eval.in/559063

Also check the difference and use of quotes : [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php/3446286#3446286)