# How to make control characters visible?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have to display string with visible control characters like `\n`, `\t` etc.
I have tried quotations like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835423/how-to-make-control-characters-visible-in-string), also I have tried to do something like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Cntrl}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
String controlChar = matcher.group();
String replace = "\\" + controlChar;
result = result.replace(controlChar, replace);
```

but I have failed

Comment: By control characters, do you only mean Java's escape characters?

Answer (score 4):

*Alternative: Use visible characters instead of escape sequences.*

To make control characters "visible", use the characters from the Unicode [Control Pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures) Block, i.e. map `\u0000`-`\u001F` to `\u2400`-`\u241F`, and `\u007F` to `\u2421`.

Note that this requires output to be Unicode, e.g. UTF-8, not a single-byte code page like ISO-8859-1.

```
private static String showControlChars(String input) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[\u0000-\u001F\u007F]").matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        char c = m.group().charAt(0);
        m.appendReplacement(buf, Character.toString(c == '\u007F' ? '\u2421' : (char) (c + 0x2400)));
        if (c == '\n') // Let's preserve newlines
            buf.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

Output using method above as input text:

```
␉private static String showControlChars(String input) {␍␊
␉␉StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();␍␊
␉␉Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[\u0000-\u001F\u007F]").matcher(input);␍␊
␉␉while (m.find()) {␍␊
␉␉␉char c = m.group().charAt(0);␍␊
␉␉␉m.appendReplacement(buf, Character.toString(c == '\u007F' ? '\u2421' : (char) (c + 0x2400)));␍␊
␉␉␉if (c == '\n')␍␊
␉␉␉␉buf.append(System.lineSeparator());␍␊
␉␉}␍␊
␉␉return m.appendTail(buf).toString();␍␊
␉}␍␊
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace occurences of `'\n'` with the escaped version (i.e. `'\\n'`), like this:

```
final String result = str.replace("\n", "\\n");
```

For example:

```
public static void main(final String args[]) {
    final String str = "line1\nline2";
    System.out.println(str);
    final String result = str.replace("\n", "\\n");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Will yield the output:

```
line1
newline
line1\nnewline
```

Answer (score 0):

just doing

```
result = result.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

will work!!

Comment: Why do you think so? What is that first ``\``?

Comment: `'\u0000'.replace('\\', '\\\\')` outputs back `'\u0000'`, probably because `'\u0000'` does not actually have a backslash character, but is a single Unicode character.