# How can I immitate Notepad++ "Show All Characters" functionality in a web-based UI

Tags: javascript, java, notepad++, special-characters

I'd like to display messages in my web-based UI for, without going into much detail as to why, remote trouble-shooting purposes over the phone. Some messages it is important to have both a carriage return and line feed, while others should just have one or the other.

Notepad++ has a Show All Characters function

[image: Show All Characters function]

that does this, and I'd like to implement something similar into my web UI.

I'd love for something that looks like

[image: this plain message]

to be able to looks like

[image: this formatted message]

Problem is, I can't find **any** information on how to do this online. The best I can find is how to escape special characters or how to implement the  tag, which isn't what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make control characters visible. See [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40893592/5221149).

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(showControlChars("I need this\r\n" +
                                        "message to show\r\n" +
                                        "with the all \r\n" +
                                        "special characters\r\n" +
                                        "\r\n"));
}
private static String showControlChars(String input) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[\u0000-\u001F\u007F]").matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        char c = m.group().charAt(0);
        m.appendReplacement(buf, Character.toString(c == '\u007F' ? '\u2421' : (char) (c + 0x2400)));
        if (c == '\n') // Let's preserve newlines
            buf.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

*Output*

```
I need this␍␊
message to show␍␊
with the all ␍␊
special characters␍␊
␍␊
```

Comment: Never came across this in my searches. I'll take a look, thank you!

Comment: Pretty sure this methodology will work. Just have to get it done client-side, not server-side. Thanks for the help again @Andreas, marked as answered